# Equal probability of rank implies identically distributed?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, order-statistics

Let $X$ and $Y$ be independent, continuous random variables. It is easy to see that if $X$ and $Y$ are identically distributed then $P(X < Y) = 1/2$.

Is the converse true? That is, for $X,Y$ independent, does $P(X<Y) = 1/2$ imply that $X$ and $Y$ are identically distributed?

Comment: Suppose $X \sim U[-1,1]$ and $Y \sim U[-2,2]$.

Comment: Indeed, any pair of symmetric distributions with the same mean will suffice.